# installing RT5370sta driver for D-Link DWA-123 rev b1 in lubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, 14.04, usb, lubuntu

I have a D-Link DWA-123 Rev B1 wireless USB dongle and found out that RT5370sta is the driver for it.

I tried to install it in vain. In the last step when you have to load the driver, the error message is:

> FATAL:Module RT5370sta not found.

Comment: Which instructions are you using. I did help maintain the wiki entry https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Tenda_W311M which covers this chipset for older versions of Ubuntu. Try following the steps under the heading rt2800usb driver.

Comment: i have tried rt2800usb already, and it results in very low connectivity and auomatic disconnection, thus i wanted to try rt5370 sta

Comment: OK, rt2800usb used to work great for me until I changed my usb dongle.

Answer (score 0):

Install the device drivers for Wifi devices:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Comment: thanx for your reply but this did not solve my problem.